# After suspend bluetooth on my Lenovo E120 can`t be turned on

Tags: 12.04, suspend, bluetooth, lenovo

After my computer wakes up from being suspended bluetooth is hard blocked : I can`t  turn ON bluetooth.

Notebook Lenovo E120

Comment: Easier way ->
 when ON notebook login in BIOS and Load Default - > Save and EXIT 
and BLUETOOTH is ON

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on reboot?

If it is truly hard-blocked,  boot into Windows (with Lenovo drivers & wireless utils) is necessary to re-enable on many (most?  all?) Lenovos in your model range.